# What is the name for functions like this: $(x,y,z)\mapsto (f(x),g(y),h(z))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

For $n=3$: $$(x,y,z)\mapsto(f(x),g(y),h(z)).$$

For arbitrary $n$: $$(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto\,(f_1(x_1),\dots,\,f_n(x_n)).$$

I don't need the answer for mathematics' sake, but to suitably name a multivariate function in some computer program that conforms to this model.

Comment: Do you have any special properties of $f_i$? Bijective? Continuous? Differentiable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refer to this as a type of (direct) product function. Namely, you have functions $f_i\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$, and you have the function $f_1\times\dots\times f_n$ given by
$$(f_1\times\dots\times f_n)(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \big(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_2),\dots,f_n(x_n)\big).$$

Comment: Why not Cartesian production ? (come to think of it)

Comment: Cartesian product? Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Actually, Cartesian product [of functions].